# Appcelerator Titanium iOS Distribution Error

Tags: ios, appcelerator-mobile

Here's the error that I'm getting when trying to distribute:

> [INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.5.1
>   [INFO] iPhone Device family: iphone
>   [INFO] iPhone SDK version: 4.2  Error:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Library/Application
>   Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py",
>   line 599, in main
>       provisioning_profile = read_provisioning_profile(pp,o)   File
>   "/Library/Application
>   Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py",
>   line 212, in read_provisioning_profile
>       f = open(f,'rb').read() IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   u'/Users/charleszink/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
>   Profiles/----(edited)----.mobileprovision'

I've downloaded, re-done, installed, and tried pretty much everything with my keys to get them to work. Not sure what the issue is. Here's what Appcelerator looks like: http://d.pr/uG5R - Nothing seems to be wrong there.

Answer (score 4):

Just copy provision profile with the name you see in an error message to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/{NAME}.mobileprovision . I had the same problem and it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just open XCode
2. open "Organizer" (if it's not open by default)
3. goto to "Provisioning Profiles" (Make sure you downloaded the correct provisioning profile 
   from your provisioning portal)
4. drag and drop the provisioning profile you downloaded on the organizer

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this issue and moving the provisioning profile didn't help. Unfortunately the message that Titanium spits out, is not really helpful.

I fixed it by opening the XCode project in the iPhone folder. From there I tried to run the project on the iPhone. XCode gave me an error as well. But the error message told me that I have 2 developer certificates in the Keychain (one was expired). Then I deleted the wrong certificate and viola, now it works.

Hope theis helps

Ray